# is it possible to change server control values in ajax call?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

e.g, I used AsycFileUpload control in AjaxToolkitControl, in UploadComplete I found I cannot change asp control values like

```
TextBox1.Text="abc"
```

is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: if the answer is no, hope someone can explain a little bit... then i ll use javascript. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just update the Textbox1.Text via jquery?

E.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function onUpLoadComplete()
  {
    $("#textbox1").val("abc");
    // or like this
    $("#textbox1").text("abc");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: i ve never used jquery. so here textbox1 is a server control's name?

Comment: textbox1 should be the id of the element. You can also use just normal javascript, you have to check the html rendered by asp to get the id of the textbox element. For argument sake the textbox id is "textbox1". Then you can use document.getElementByID("textbox1").value = "abc";

Comment: sorry my bad it is getElementById

Comment: thanks...in fact i need to update a asp checkboxlist, i just used textbox for example. i ll consider using javascript if changing server side control value is not possible, but the javascript part will be more complicated than using a server control.